# How to toggle visibility of a html element which is not a sibling of the checkbox element by using CSS ONLY

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        #check:checked+p {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <label for="check">Toggle</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="" id="check">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing el nemo natus atque in cupiditate sint.</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to toggle the visibility of the p tag in the second div , is there any pseudo-selector that I can use?

Comment: Perchance, using the native `details` HTML element couldn't solve your task without using CSS hacks?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details

Answer (score 0):

There is using the `:has()` pseudo class but this isn't fully supported yet (particularly firefox).

The logic works by selecting the body if the input with the id of `#check` is checked. If so then the paragraph in the 2nd child of the body is hidden.

More info on :has on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) and [CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/the-css-has-selector/)

For compatibility see [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas)

```css
body:has(#check:checked) div:nth-child(2) p {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <label for="check">Toggle</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="" id="check">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing el nemo natus atque in cupiditate sint.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```